# Python Linter installation issue with VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[warning VSCode newbie here]
When installing pylinter from within VScode I got this message:
The script isort.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\fjanssen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
Which is correct. However, my Python is installed in C:\Program Files\Python37\

So I am thinking Python is installed for all users, while pylinter seems to be installed for the user (me).

Checking the command-line that VScode threw to install pylinter it indeed seems to install for the user:

> & "C:/Program Files/Python37/python.exe" -m pip install -U pylint --user

So, I have some questions on resolving this issue;
1 - how can I get the immediate issue resolved?
- remove pylinter as user
- re-install for all users

2 - Will this (having python installed for all users) keep bugging me in the future? 
- should I re-install python for the current user only when using it with VScode?

Comment: Is there a full Python installed in the `AppData\Roaming` directory? Removed the instaled pylint and use the command line to call `pip` from the `Python37\Scripts` directory.

Comment: I created a mess I think, I now have paths for both appdata\loacal and appdata\roaming added to my environment variables to get ridd of all errors.
Looking for a working methode to restart this completely (remove python, vscode, then completely start over with setting up my system.)
I tried that, but the Python setup wouldn't add to my path  ?

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to simply use pylint with VS Code, then you don't need to install it globally. Create a virtual environment and select that in VS Code as your Python interpreter and then pylint will be installed there instead of globally. That way you don't have to worry about `PATH`.